# Symbol of commutant of two pseudo -differential operators is in $S^{m+n-1}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $T_{\tau},T_{\sigma}$ be two pseudo -differential operators with $\sigma \in S^m, \tau\in S^n$, how to prove that the symbol of $T_{\tau}\circ T_{\sigma}-T_{\sigma}\circ T_{\tau}$ is in $S^{m+n-1}$?